# How emberjs function is invoked?

Tags: ember.js

I want to understand how the function in plugin is invoked.

Here's the code snippet from [discourse-adplugin](https://github.com/discourse/discourse-adplugin)

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  ...
  _initGoogleDFP: function() {
    var self = this;
    loadGoogle(this.siteSettings).then(function() {
      ...
    });
  }.on('didInsertElement'),
  ...
});
```

There's no mention that the `_initGoogleDFP` function is evidently invoking by somebody but it's somehow invokes from guts of `emberjs`.

What is the principles of initialising `emberjs` components?
How `_initGoogleDFP` is invoking by `emberjs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Ember.on` function (or `Function.prototype.on`) returns a special function with some Ember implementation details:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  ...
  _initGoogleDFP: <some-special-function-object>,
  ...
});
```

Ember iterates the keys in your class definition, looking for these special objects, and eventually calls `Ember.addListener('didInsertElement', yourFunction)`.

---

You should generally avoid using `.on`. It's confusing. If you have two `.on('didInsertElement')`, in which order do they get called? Who knows.

The preferred way to write your code is to override `didInsertElement`:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  ...
  didInsertElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    var self = this;
    loadGoogle(this.siteSettings).then(function() {
      ...
    });
  }
  ...
});
```

If you need to call `_initGoogleDFP` from other places, make it a function and you can call it from `didInsertElement`:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  ...
  _initGoogleDFP: function() {
    var self = this;
    loadGoogle(this.siteSettings).then(function() {
      ...
    });
  },

  didInsertElement() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this._initGoogleDFP();
  }
  ...
});
```

Comment: This code is from discourse plugin, that's why they hook up on the didInsertElement event, the component will load asynchronically in discourse environment.